# Is it possible to show the playlist and video for VLC at the same time?

Tags: vlc

This was asked and answered a number of years ago, but it seems the old option was removed. Is the option living somewhere else now that I just can't seem to find or has it been removed entirely?

I am running VLC 3.0.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prefs > Video > Show video within the main window

Uncheck for separate playback window

[image]

Comment: Perfect! That seems very obvious now that I've seen it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Need to restart after make the changed